# How can I create a shared workgroup account for a Windows 8 Online account?

Tags: windows-8, user-accounts, windows-home-server, workgroup, microsoft-surface

I have a number of machines ranging from a Windows Server 2003 based Home Server, a couple of Windows 7 machines and now a Windows 8 Surface.

I'd like to be able to seamlessly access my media library on the workgroup from the Surface, and think the best way to do that would be to create an account on the Home Server a that matches my Live account on the surface.

How do I find the windows account name of the Online account so I can create duplicate accounts on the other machines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the actual account names, press <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> and then select "Computer Management". In the MMC, under System Tools, expand "Local Users and Groups", and then click on "Users" - you'll see all the actual accounts in there:

[image: Users pane of Computer Management]

Mostly these will be the first names you've specified on the Online accounts, but in some cases they may be padded: for example, one of the accounts appears to be:

- carol_000

I believe the core of the account linking is actually handled by the Windows Home Server Console app that can be installed on Windows 7 and lower - I've not yet installed 8 properly, only Windows RT.

The WHS Console would automatically configure a number of shared folders for the accounts that are configured on the local machine when it is installed, and presumably would add your local credentials to the Credential Manager but for the WHS name thus allowing "seamless" interaction with the server over the workgroup - which is really just a way of grouping an otherwise disparate, unconnected set of machines.