# Accessing a WHS 2003 Share from Windows 8

Tags: windows-home-server, windows-8

I have a Windows Home Server 2003 running with my shared files on it. I've recently updated my  desktop computer with Windows 8 and I'm now unable to access the public shares on the WHS box. I did use a Windows Live login for the Win 8 Box. The WHS connector installed just fine, and it is collecting backups of my Win 8 box.

I noticed that there's a local user named mobyt_000 (My hotmail name is mobytoby). I attempted to create a user in the WHS admin console named mobyt_000 and although it did create it, I still can't get access to that share or any other one that isn't open to "Guest". What's also strange is I now get prompted for my WHS password everytime I log in. I can put in identical passwords for the WHS account, and my local win8 account and although it seems to satisfy that dialog (the green check appears), the very next time I dbl-click the WHS icon in the tray it again prompts me for updated creds.

I see anonymous access errors in the WHS Security logs, but have no idea what I *should* be seeing in there.

Any ideas?

Comment: You might want to check out my question here on this: [How can I create a shared workgroup account for a Windows 8 Online Account](http://superuser.com/q/501424/3186) where I was trying to do exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out. I decided to compare local security policies between my WHS box and my new Windows 8 Desktop. I stumbled on a setting named ["Server SPN target name validation level"](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh125918%28v=ws.10%29.aspx#BKMK_35b). It was undefined on Win 8 and non-existent on my WHS box. I set my Win8 box to use "Accept if provided by client" and all of my shares now work.

Comment: If you go back and register your Server Fault account you can take back the question

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you mean? Re-post it back on Server Fault?

Comment: No, just go on Server Fault and register your account with the same details you used here. After that everything should take care of itself. Do not re-ask the question